# Visual Studio chart line below zero

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

This is chart i have [image]

i am printing it with this code :

```
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            MySqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (sqlReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    string Sum = sqlReader["Sum"].ToString();
                    if (Sum.Contains(",")) Sum = Sum.Replace(",", ".");

                    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(Sum);
                    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(i + 0.5, i + 1.5, sqlReader["Year"].ToString() + '\'' + sqlReader["Month"].ToString() + '\'' + sqlReader["Day"].ToString());

                    chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
```

and i am interested, is it possible to change line color if point is below zero? For example if line above 0 it is green, if below - red?

Update: Not the whole line! Only part above/below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own [question over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162013/mschart-line-graph-with-dashed-style-and-large-amount-of-data-points/12177555#12177555) on taking over the drawing of an MSChart (to get line styles to actually work).  It would be fairly simple to modify the code to change the colour if y was less than 0 :)